# Is this a right position to place "See more" button on the top of particular section in "Google Store"?

Tags: buttons, google

[image: Google play screen shot]

Google placed the "See more" button on top of each section. I wrongly clicked the bottom button of "Apps" section to see all kind of similar app. But it showed me all book apps. Then I pressed back botton and then only I came to know there is other "See more" option on top of it. It confused me initially, so I decided to ask the same in UX stackexchange members.

Comment: No, it is not right position when it confuses the users. It should be visually clear to what section the button belongs.

Answer (score 1):

When I had seen it for the first time, I was searching for the appropriate button too. Although the ruler suggestion is good enough, I would recommend a simpler option.

I would place a see more with a count as an semitransparent overlay on the last item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's confusing and I agreed with you. In my opinion, we can improve this simply by adding a ruler... [image]